# Form Freezes When Moving Files

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, filesystems, backgroundworker

So I'm currently using a `BackgroundWorker1_DoWork` to create PDF files. On the `BackgroundWorker1RunWorker1_Completed` I'm using the following code to move those files from one  locaton to another.

```
        'MOVE PDFs TO NEW LOCATION
        For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("C:\Temp\", FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.pdf")
            Dim foundFileInfo As New System.IO.FileInfo(foundFile)
            'ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Moving PDFs..."
            File.Move(foundFile, "\\server\temp\" & foundFileInfo.Name) 'MOVES PDFs
        Next
```

When the program gets to this point, my form freezes up, can't move the window, can't scroll, can't do anything within the program.

What would cause my form to freeze? Is there any way to eliminate this?

Comment: Why on Earth would you put this code in the RunWorkerCompleted event?  Put it in your DoWork event handler instead.

Comment: Why not just move the files in the backgroundworker too?

Comment: I'm using a For Each statmement in the DoWork to create the PDFs. I was having problem waiting for that process to complete before proceeding. Even though I'm using `psinfo.WaitForExit()`, I haven't figured out why and thus any code after my For Each runs before the files are fully created. Which is why I decided to move the PDFs once the DoWork is completed.

Comment: @Muhnamana I've updated my answer to address that concern.

Comment: Did your app ever came back from the freeze when this happened or did it freeze permanently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Completed` event is raised from the UI thread.  Therefore, any work that you do in that event handler will block the UI until it is done processing.  If you don't want to cause the UI to freeze, you need to do the `File.Move` in the `DoWork` event handler, since that is the one which is raised from the background thread.

**Update**

Based on your comment above, you need to remember that the `DoWork` event handler is raised from a background thread.  Therefore, you can block that thread for as long as you want without affecting the UI responsiveness.  Therefore, if you are having an issue with the file not yet being available after the process exits, I would recommend retrying the `File.Move` in a loop.  You could retry the file move operation several times, with a short `Thread.Sleep` in between so that if it still fails after a certain amount of time, it will timeout and fail.  For instance, this will retry the file once per second and then timeout after 10 seconds:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 10
    Try
        File.Move(foundFile, "\\server\temp\" & foundFileInfo.Name)
        Exit For
    Catch ex As IOException
    End Try
    Thread.Sleep(1000)
Next
```

Comment: I'll bring him back out...it ties well into my username! :)

Comment: This timeout of 10 seconds, if PDFs are created after those 10 seconds they won't get moved correct? Thus finding the optimal timeout is warranted?

Comment: Reason I ask is because the process of creating those PDFs goes into a queue, so depending on how many requests are ahead of mine, it may take 10 mins, 40 mins or 5 mins to create X amount of PDFs.

Comment: Right.  If it really takes that long for the files to get created, you would probably be better off using the `FileSystemWatcher` to find out when files get created.  The `FileSystemWatcher` listens for notifications from the OS to find out when file events occur.  It's more efficient than sitting in a loop constantly polling.

Comment: `FileSystemWatcher` worked perfect! As the files were creating, they were also moving at the same time.

Comment: Yay!  Yes, that sounds like a much cleaner solution in this case.